ZPL: ^FN1 not show all content when used in ^BQ command
I am trying to generate a QR code that contains RFID data.
But, in the code data the first 3 characters are missing. I know this issue when using the ^FD command. Here, you need to format the data by using the QR code switches, e.g. ^FDQA, MyText. This works fine.
But I am using ^FN to get the result of the ^RF command:
^XA
^DFR:MYFORMAT.ZPL^FS
^FO210,50^A0N,30,30^FDTag Data:^FS
^FO210,100^A0N,30,30^FN1^FS
^FO250,130
^BQN,2,6^FN1^FS
^XZ


^XA
^XFR:MYFORMAT.ZPL^FS
^FN1^RFR,H,0,1,E^FS
^XZ

The QR code gets generated, but missing the first 3 characters.
All other codes will be generated with correct content (e.g. PDF417, Datamatrix, Code128).
I also tried to format the content by using the QR-Code switches in the ^FD command.
^FN1^FDQA,^RFR,H,0,64,E^FS

But in this case, I get an unreadable QR code.
